# Stop js values going into negative

Tags: javascript, increment

I have a problem with an increment function that allows users to press a button to add or remove tickets. However I don't want the user to be able to go into the negative's and screw everything up. Is there any way i can stop this from happening. A working demo can be found at http://kentishtours.co.uk/destinations/canterbury.php and the blue "-" "+" buttons are what i'm talking about.

Thanks

[image]

Code that is used to recognize input and increment the number.

```
var adult = $('#adult'),
child = $('#child'),
total = $('.total'),
value = $('#value'),
increase = $('#increase'),
decrease = $('#decrease'),
increasec = $('#increasec'),
decreasec = $('#decreasec');

var calulate_price = function(a, c){   
 var p1 = 18,
  p2 = 10,
  PA = a * p1,
  PC, d;

if(a >= 1) PC = c * p2;
else PC = c * p1;

d = PA + PC;

total.text("£ " + d + ".00");
value.val(d);
};

increase.click(function(){
var a = Number(adult.val());
var c = Number(child.val());  
adult.val(++a);
calulate_price(a, c);
}); 
decrease.click(function(){
var a = Number(adult.val());
var c = Number(child.val());  
adult.val(--a);
calulate_price(a, c);
}); 
increasec.click(function(){
var a = Number(adult.val());
var c = Number(child.val());  
child.val(++c);
calulate_price(a, c);
}); 
decreasec.click(function(){
var a = Number(adult.val());
var c = Number(child.val());  
child.val(--c);
calulate_price(a, c);
});
```

Comment: existing code will help

Comment: As a rule of thumb, we always want code.

Comment: A small sample of the addition code would help then we can find your error.

Comment: please create a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `if (x > 0) { add ... }`

Comment: Basically just put an `if` statement around whatever code is decrementing the variable.

Comment: `if (number < 0) number = 0` doh

Comment: @crush, i'm interested to know how you're going to get `number` to be greater than `Number.MAX_VALUE` (Infinity, I suppose, but how would you get there?)

Comment: @zzzzBov blonde moment disregard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
decrease.click(function(){
  var a = Number(adult.val());
  var c = Number(child.val());
  if(a>0){
   adult.val(--a);
  }
  calulate_price(a, c);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Only a beginner, so simple if you know how. Thanks Again!

Comment: yes that works, but disabling the button is a better solution from as far as user experience is concerned

Answer (score 6):

You could do several things:

- Disable the button when 0, so you cant go negative.
- If the user posts a negative value, always take 0 (server side check)
- If click on minus icon, and value is below 0, make it 0 again.

Just 3 possible options, I bet there are more left. ;)

Note, you always want to check the input server side, especially when it comes to money :)

Comment: haha and the best solution is the one I offered first and got - 1 for. Good work

Comment: Yours was a "note" which you edited afterwards. Glad I got the points, they will be a bounty soon.

Comment: yes... my original answer could have been phrased better and the grammar checked before I posted.

Answer (score 3):

Disable the minus button if the `value == 0`

```
decrease = $('#decrease');

//set inital state
if(Number(adult.val())==0){
  $('#decrease').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}else{
  $('#decrease').removeAttr("disabled");
}

increase.click(function(){
  var a = Number(adult.val());
  adult.val(++a);
  //make sure its enabled any time we're > 0    
  if(a>0){
    $('#decrease').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  var c = Number(child.val()); 
  calulate_price(a, c);
}); 
decrease.click(function(){
  var a = Number(adult.val());
  adult.val(--a);
  //disable if we are back to 0
  if(a==0){
    $('#decrease').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  var c = Number(child.val());  
  calulate_price(a, c);
});
```

Comment: Simple problems only require simple solutions

Comment: +1 can probably be simplified a bit, e.g. `$("#decrease").prop('disabled', !a);`

Comment: definitely.  I would update but since this solution is targeted towards a beginner, I think that what I have might be easier to read and understand.